# Declaring an array in Swift

Tags: swift

What's the difference between these 3:

```
struct A {
  let myVal: Array<Char>
  let myVal2: [char]
  let myVal3: Array<CChar>
}
```

Which one is more common or recommended to be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference between `Array<Thing>` and `[Thing]`; the latter is syntactic sugar for the former.

Hence the only difference between your three declarations is the difference between the three element types: Char (whatever that is), char (whatever that is - a type name starting with a small letter is really bad practice in Swift, though), and CChar (that's the only one I've ever heard of). The recommended one of those three is: whatever it is you want an array of.

Answer (score 0):

CChar is Swift equivalent of C Primitive type - It is recommended to use Swift data type where it is possibl.- [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html)

The recommended usage as per this [style guide](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide) is the shortcut version

myValue: [CChar]

Hope this helps